# Setting the relative path in java

Tags: java

I have a java file which needs to read from another java file in the same package. However, when I am using the following code , it shows `FilenotFoundException`.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/wordlist.txt"));
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: So, file is not found. Is it in the root directory? I doubt so. Try "wordlist.txt".

Comment: if your .java file is in the same directory as wordlist.txt,`FileReader('wordlist.txt')`will work

Comment: `wordlist.txt` is not a Java file and it is therefore not in a package at all. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this :

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("wordlist.txt"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never start paths with `/`. In Linux this means you refer to the root. You can simply use `"wordlist.txt"` if the file is in the same folder as the current directory or `"folder/file.txt"` if it is located in some folder below. You can use `..` to refer to the parent folder like `"../brother/file"`